# Is @media resolution dppx The Same Value As window.devicePixelRatio?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm in the process of creating background image selection statements in my WordPress theme's (Avada v7.4.1) child theme external `style.css` stylesheet. The CSS @media `resolution` feature is described by MDN Web Docs as a *"value representing the pixel density of the output device." Is the "pixel density of the output device"* the browser viewport pixel density or the native pixel density of the device's display screen?

For example, on a 3840 x 2160 4K UHD desktop monitor, the monitor's native Device Pixel Density ("DPR") is 1.0 when Windows 10 display scaling is set to 100%; the JavaScript variable `window.devicePixelDensity` returns 1.0, which is expected. When Windows 10 display scaling is set to 175% (which is what I have done), the JavaScript variable `window.devicePixelDensity` returns 1.75, which is also expected. Is the @media resolution dppx value in this example 1.0 (the display screen's native DPR) or 1.75 (the browser viewport's DPR)?